# Loop array in mysql query and for the result

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to loop a mysql query and display every result on new row. I know i'm missing some pices, do i need to SET variable in mysql instead?

```
$value = array(B1,B2,B3,B4);
$query = "SELECT SUM($value[0]) AS ".$value[0]."_SUM, "
    ."SUM(answer_value) AS ".$value[0]."_ANSWER_SUM "
    ."FROM questions q JOIN answers a ON q.question_id = a.question_id "
    ."WHERE $value[0]=1";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$value[0]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['B1_ANSWER_SUM']."</td>";  
    echo "<td>".$row['B1_SUM'] ."</td>"; 
    echo '</tr>' ;  
}
```

I would like to get this result:

```
B1 B1_ANSWER_SUM B1_SUM
B2 B2_ANSWER_SUM B2_SUM
B3 B2_ANSWER_SUM B2_SUM
```

Comment: If B1, B2, etc. are supposed to be string values, be sure to encapsulate them in quotes: `$value = array('B1','B2','B3','B4');` Otherwise, the PHP engine will try to interpret them as constants which don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through your array and query each item in the array. See below:

```
$value = array('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4');

foreach ($value as $v) {
    $query = "SELECT SUM($v) AS ".$v."_SUM, SUM(answer_value) AS ".$v."_ANSWER_SUM FROM questions q JOIN answers a ON q.question_id = a.question_id WHERE $v=1";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$v."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row[$v.'_ANSWER_SUM']."</td>";  
        echo "<td>".$row[$v.'_SUM'] ."</td>"; 
        echo '</tr>' ;  
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for your help. I'm struggeling with the echo loop. I Think this is just a sumary of b1, b2 ,b3, b4 ? : while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results[$v])) {
  
  echo $row['B1_SUM'], $row['B1_ANSWER_SUM'];
 }

Comment: that just echo´s the B1 as a summary i think? I need to the values of b1, b2, b3, b4 on separate rows?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated again. I missed dynamically changing the column name in the while loop